# Pagination doesn't appear using dataTables

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have an object that came from  the laravel  controller and i extracted it to a table
when i used

```
 let table = $("#underConstructions-table").dataTable({
                    paging: true,
                    info: false,    
                    searching: true,});
```

there is no difference . my dataTble version is 1.10.20

Comment: You probably want to show what is the html for your selector $("#underConstructions-table") because with the info you put there no way to know what datatables is actually doing.

Comment: You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for guidance on how to improve your question. You should also take a look at [mre] and provide that in your question. Take a look at other DataTables questions to see how they have provided a MRE. Take a look at the basic [examples](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/index.html) in the official DataTables web site for more guidance.

Comment: Not an answer (because it's not the cause of your problem), but you should typically use `DataTable()` and not `dataTable()`. They both work for basic tables, but there is a [difference](https://datatables.net/reference/api/).